# How do I set Backbone Views as singleton by default?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, singleton, amd

all my Backbone.Views are only used once in their final state. (Except item views).

Currently I handle Backbone.Views as Singleton this way:

```
var Singletonizer = function(Singleton) {
    if (Singleton._instance) return Singleton._instance;

    Singleton._instance = new Singleton();

    Singletonizer(Singleton);
};
```

Unfortunately it isn't that nice to add this little function as dependency to each amd module in my repository.

Is there another way to handle this? Maybe overwriting the base view class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the very recommendable book [Recipes with Backbone](http://recipeswithbackbone.com/):

From here:

```
// definition
MyApplication.Views.List = Backbone.View.extend();

// instantiation
$(function() {
  MyApplication.ListView = new MyApplication.Views.List({
    el: $('#list')
  }); 
})
```

To here:

```
$(function() {
  MyApplication.ListView = new (Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
      // ...
    }
  }))({el: $('#list')})
});
```

> We assign an instantiation of an anonymous class to `MyApplication.ListView`. In this approach, we are doing the typical extension of a top-level Backbone class with custom attributes and methods. The difference, however, is that we do *not* assign the result to a class name as we did earlier. Instead, we immediately create a *new* instance of this anonymous class. Lastly, `MyApplication.ListView` is assigned to the resulting object.

I have to say I've never used techniques like this. It looks to messy for me, I prefer legibility than architecture.

Comment: Hi, I still don't understand the logic behind this pattern. Shouldn't the second one still create a second object?

Comment: _second object_? I don't understand what do you mean. With the second implementation you obtain an already instante `Backbone.View` customized to your convenience and that is not possible to create new instances of.

Answer (score 6):

Just have your module return a function besides your view constructor, one that returns a single instance of it instead, not unlike the following.  This way when you load the module you will not automatically get an instance whether you like it or not.  Instead, after loading our "FailedXhrView" module, we then get our singleton by calling `FailedXhrView()`

```
'use strict';

define(['jquery', 
        'underscore', 
        'backbone', 
        'text!templates/failedXhr.html'], 

function($, _, Backbone, failedXhrTemplate) {
    var FailedXhrView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el : $('#failedxhr-modal-container'),
        template : _.template(failedXhrTemplate),

        render : function() {
            this.$el.html(this.template({}));
            this.$el.find('failedxhr-modal-containee').modal();
            return this;
        }
    });

    var instance;

    return function() {
        if (!instance) {
            instance = new FailedXhrView();
        }
        return instance;
    }
});
```

Comment: Instead of returning an instantiated FailedXhrView from that module IMO it's a bit nicer to create a "singleton" module that does nothing more than take FailedXhrView as a dependency and then return an instantiated instance.  This gives you a little more flexibility for testing the original module, since you'll probably want to instantiate it within the test itself.